# How do I make my Angular 8 application use the whole viewport?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am developing a single-page application consisting of a navbar and a router-outlet which displays the component selected in the navbar. The primary component which loads by default is a Leaflet map which I would like to fill the entire page aside from the navbar. Currently I cannot even get the main component to fill the whole page, as it insists on including white space on the sides. I've set the container to have a high-res background image so I can see how much space it is actually filling.

The main page with all its unnecessary whitespace
[image: The main page with all its unnecessary whitespace]

The code:

**app.component.html**

```
<body>
  <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
  <div class="container" id="main-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</body>
```

**styles.css**

```
body {
height: 98vh;
width: 98vw;
}

html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

#main-container {
  background-image: url("src/assets/chicago-wallpaper.jpg");
  width: 98vw;
  height: 94vh;
}
```

Comment: It is always good to create a demo of your issue. It would be easy for others to test it and provide you a solution.

Comment: Sure, that'd make sense. I'm fairly new to Angular development, how would I go about making a simple demo for this?

Comment: You should use online editors like we have stackblitz(https://stackblitz.com/) for creating angular demos.
Create a new angular demo and share your link here

Comment: It kind of looks, from your screenshot, like you are using bootstrap? That will make the `.container` have a max-width.

Comment: Thank you, Matthew Allen. This seems to have solved the issue. Embarrassingly simple.

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Don't put the word "solved" in the question.

Comment: Stackoverflow won't let me. The answer was given in a comment, which I cannot mark as the answer. It also won't let me mark my own answer as the solution for another two days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matthew Allen seems to have supplied the embarrassingly simple answer. Bootstrap had applied a max-width rule to .container, and setting "max-width: none" in styles.css lets the map fill the page.

Answer (score 1):

The body tag in your html page has a default padding.

So, you need to remove that padding by adding the following code.

"style.css"

```
body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh; /* This take the whole viewport height */

   margin: 0;
   padding: 0; /* Remove the default padding */
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `float:left` to all elements in the css that could help.

Comment: This does not change the amount of whitespace, rather it just moves it all to the right of the main container.